# Using PHP DOMDocument, find then loop through image tags below find

Tags: php, html

I know how to loop though html tags using DOM getElementsByTagName from top to bottom.

Is it possible to tell the loop where to actually start based on possibly a find or line number?

Example:

- I have a comment in the file `<!-- Start Here -->`
- Find the comment in file
- Loop through img tags below the comment

Comment: You can use php [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), I am too lazy to create an example, sorry

Comment: Is the purpose of this to improve performance? Or do you wish to ignore results prior to this comment?

Comment: Is there some code you've tried so far?

Comment: @MuhammadIbnuh please don't suggest `simple_html_dom`, it's terrible and there are [much better options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/283366)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) query could do what you are asking.  You can select all the `img` tags after a specific comment like this:

```
$domDoc->load('/path/to/your/html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDoc);
$qry = "//comment()[. = ' Start Here ']/following::img";

$results = $xpath->query($qry);
```

`$results` now contains an iterable list of all the `img` tags that occur after the comment. You can then process your images however you'd like. For instance, this would print out the `src` attribute for each `img`:

```
foreach($results as $img){
    echo $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Note, in the above loop, `$img` is a [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) object so you can manipulate it using those functions.

Depending on how complex your real use case is, I'd encourage you to read into [XPath syntax](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xpath), it can be a very powerful tool for DOM parsing.

Comment: @halfer I wish to ignore results above.

Comment: I never used XPath so I appreciate the suggestion and link to the syntax.  Your code worked perfectly.